# Yii urlManager settings lead to 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, yii

The url localhost/photogallery works, but every link leads to a 404.

By the way, the links worked perfectly fine before I changed the settings of the urlManager.

Example:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /photogallery/site/page was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

It worked before I modified the main.php in the config folder.

.htaccess

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 IndexIgnore */*

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L] 
 </IfModule>
```

main.php

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
        'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
        'name'=>'My Web Application',

        // preloading 'log' component
        'preload'=>array('log'),

        // autoloading model and component classes
        'import'=>array(
                'application.models.*',
                'application.components.*',
        ),

        'modules'=>array(
                // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

                'gii'=>array(
                        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
                        'password'=>'allo',
                        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
                        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
                ),

        ),
    // application components
    'components'=>array(

            'user'=>array(
                    // enable cookie-based authentication
                    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            ),

            // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

            'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat' => 'path',
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => array(               
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                ),
            ),


            // database settings are configured in database.php
            'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

            'errorHandler'=>array(
                    // use 'site/error' action to display errors
                    'errorAction'=>YII_DEBUG ? null : 'site/error',
            ),

            'log'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
                    'routes'=>array(
                            array( 
                                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                                    'levels'=>'error, warning, trace',
                            ),
                            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

                            array(
                                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                                    'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
                            ),

                    ),
            ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
            // this is used in contact page
            'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
            'uploads'=>'/uploads',    
    ),
);
```

I am wondering if there are any specific configuration that needs to be done in order to run it on the default Apache server configuration. I don't want to change the settings, because I use many other php frameworks and I don't want to break things.

Changed .htaccess to:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 IndexIgnore */*

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
 </IfModule>
```

Still not working.

Comment: I guest the problem is not on config main.php..
Try this in your .htaccess

Change:
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]

To:
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

OR:
RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: I did it, but it's still not working. Do I have to do something in particular? I am running wamp on Windows.

Comment: Is your apache rewrite engine enable?

Comment: try to check it if is enable.. check this link http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,30758,30758

Comment: mod_rewrite was checked when I clicked the tray apache, apache module and scrolled down to mod_rewrite

Comment: did you see this line of code
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
from Apache -> httpd.conf ?

Comment: modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.s

Comment: Not sure if the lack of # matters. I added it and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Remove `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> </IfModule>` in your .htaccess

Then refresh the page if you get error 500 or server error. then the problem is your apache rewrite engine disabled.

[image]

if you get this error look for httpd.conf of your apache.

then look for this line of code

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

uncomment this line of code by removing #. Then dont forget to restart your apache.

Check this links:

How to enable mod_rewrite
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,30758,30758

Yii URL Management
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x

How to remove index.php from URL
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7803-how-to-remove-index-php-from-url/